# the training accuracy steadily increase, but training loss decrease and then increase

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, deep-learning, face-recognition

I have trained a face recognition model with tensorflow (4301 classes). The training process goes like follows(I have grab the chart of the training process):
[training accuracy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHxZ7.png)
[training loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEfAk.png)

The training accuracy steadily increases,  However, for the training loss, it firstly decreases, then after a  certain number of iterations, it weirdly increases.

I simply use softmax loss with weights regularizer. And I use AdamOptimizer to minimize the loss. For learning rate setting, the initial lr is set to 0.0001, the learning rate would decrease by half by every 7 epocs(380000 training images total, batch size is 16). And I have test on a validation set (consist 8300 face images),and get a validation accuracy about 55.0% which is far below the training accuracy.

Is it overfitting ? can overfitting leads to a final increase for the training loss?

Comment: Hard to tell not knowing what optimizer do you use, what loss function etc.
Does the model work correctly after all, i.e. have you checked the results manually?

Answer (score 0):

Overfitting is when you start having a divergence in the performance on training and test data — this is not the case here since you are reporting training performance only.

Training is running a minimization algorithm on your loss. When your loss starts increasing, it means that training fails at what it is supposed to be doing. You probably want to change your minimization settings to get your training loss to eventually converge.

As for why your accuracy continues to increase long after your loss starts diverging, it is hard to tell without knowing more. An explanation could be that your loss is a sum of different terms, for example a cross-entropy term and a regularization term, and that only the later diverges.

Comment: Does is it because my total losses contains a softmax loss(for classification) and a weights regulizer, as the training accuracy goes higher along with total loss goes higher , the softmax loss still decreases and the weights regulizer just increase even more to lead a total loss increase?

Comment: yes exactly, that is what I presume from what you describe. You could check by plotting the graphs of the different parts of your loss.